# UIInterfaceOrientaion not following app rules

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios5, uiinterfaceorientation

I've been having a huge problem with this.
Xcode just simply turned my landscape mode app into a portrait view and It doesn't go back !

I've programmed the entire app almost to run in landscape mode in the Ipad.

On the Storyboard, every window is in lanscape.
I believe i did the settings correctly according to the images below

[image]

[image]

and finally on my viewController I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}
```

Anybody know what could be going wrong or why would Xcode just set the screen to portrait out of nowhere while I was just adjusting a viewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only support landscape then change `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        return YES;
    }
    // Default
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I copied and pasted the code on all view controllers now it works. Thanks !